# ¿Qué puede estar fallando en este código?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de crear un generador de contraseñas, pero no sé en que estoy fallando y ya realmente no se como continuar, aquí les dejo el código:

```js
let password = document.getElementById("password");
let abc = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!#$%&/()=?¿¡";
let length = parseInt(number.value);

// let generar = (number.value) =>{

//     let result = "";
//     for(let i = 0; i <= length; i++){
//         result += abc.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * abc.length));
//     }
    
// }

function generar (length){
    let result = "";
    for(let i = 0; i <= length; i++){
        result += abc.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * abc.length));
    }
    password.value = result;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="number" name="number" id="number">
    <button id="button" onclick="generar()">GENERAR</button>
    <input type="text" id="password" readonly>

    <script src="nashe.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que la longitud la estas tomando al iniciar el script y no al presionar el botón... y la funcion generar no puede recibir el parametro desde el click.

Entonces quite el parametro de la funcion y estoy obteniendo la longitud dentro de la funcion.

```js
let password = document.getElementById("password");
let abc = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!#$%&/()=?¿¡";

function generar (){
    let length = number.value;
    let result = "";
    for(let i = 0; i < length; i++){
        result += abc.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * abc.length));
    }
    password.value = result;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="number" name="number" id="number">
    <button id="button" onclick="generar()">GENERAR</button>
    <input type="text" id="password" readonly>

    <script src="nashe.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias no te das una idea de lo que me ayudaste, gracias por tomarte un tiempo y responderme!